# After delay, check if browser is still open

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, delegates

I have a problem. After 30 seconds, I need to check if a user still has my web application `(ASP.NET framework 3.5)` open and then send some data to my database. Currently i am using the `System.Timers.Timer` class to wait 30 seconds, and then it calls a method that tries to access the `page.response.IsClientConnected`

```
System.Timers.Timer Checker = new System.Timers.Timer();
Checker.AutoReset = false;
Checker.Interval = 30000;
Checker.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ExtendLock);
Checker.Enabled = true;
```

The ExtendLock method

```
private void ExtendLock(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
         //do stuff
     }
}
```

However, when the method is called, it cannot access the properties of the control box, is this because it is within a different thread? Can somebody suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think `IsClientConnected` is doing what you think it's doing.  From what I read in the docs, it's about the TCP connection opened by the browser to request a page, not about whether a user is still viewing that page.

Comment: @adv12 Do you know of anything that allows me to check if browser is still open server side?

Comment: I don't know of anything except having the browser periodically ping the server with an AJAX request or something along those lines.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that but thanks anyway